# How to add tool-tips in d3 js vertically grouped bar chart

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, tooltip

I was creating an animated grouped bar chart. I was able to create a simple vertical grouped bar chart by the code provided below. Now I like to add some tool-tips which will show some specific data about the bar. For example, "Letter:A,Frequency:0.05". Can anyone help me out in this case.Thanks in advance :)

```js
 
    var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    
    var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
    
    var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();
    
    
    var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);
    
    
    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
    
    
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x0)
    .orient("bottom");
    
    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));
    
    
    //console.log(margin.left);
    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    
    var data = [
  {letter: "A", frequency: .08167,depth:.32},
  {letter: "B", frequency: .01492,depth:.69}
];
    var groupNames=d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key){return key!="letter";})
    
    data.forEach(function(d){
        d.groups=groupNames.map(function(name){return {name:name,value:+d[name]};})
    });
    
    
    
    x0.domain(data.map(function(d){ alert(d.letter);return d.letter;}));
    x1.domain(groupNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
    
    y.domain([0,d3.max(data,function(d){
        return d3.max(d.groups,function(d){
            return d.value;
        });
    })]);
    
     svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);
    
    svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Letter Fun");

    var letter = svg.selectAll(".letter")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "g")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.letter) + ",0)"; });
    
    letter.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.groups; })
  .enter().append("rect")
     .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
     .attr("x", function(d) {alert(d.name); return x1(d.name); })
     .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
     .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
     .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });
    
    letter.selectAll("text")
  .data(function(d) { return d.groups; })
        .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class","barstext")
        .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
        .attr("y",function(d) { return y(d.value); })
        .text(function(d){return d.value;})
    
    var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
      .data(groupNames.slice().reverse())
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "legend")
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

  legend.append("rect")
      .attr("x", width - 18)
      .attr("width", 18)
      .attr("height", 18)
      .style("fill", color);

  legend.append("text")
      .attr("x", width - 24)
      .attr("y", 9)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: instead of a `title='hello'` attribute like HTML uses, SVG uses `<title>hello</title>` tags inside an element to display a tooltip, in most browsers. so, you just need to `append()` a "title" tag.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:** Add letter information to the groups data.

```
data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.groups = groupNames.map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      letter: d.letter,
      value: +d[name]
    };
  })
});
```

**Step 2:** Append title to bars.

```
.append("title")
.text(function(d,i){
     var name = d.name.replace(/^./,d.name[0].toUpperCase());
     return "Letter : "+d.letter+" \n"+name+" : "+d.value;
});
```

```js
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();


var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);


var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);


var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));


//console.log(margin.left);
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


var data = [{
  letter: "A",
  frequency: .08167,
  depth: .32
}, {
  letter: "B",
  frequency: .01492,
  depth: .69
}];

var groupNames = d3.keys(data[0]).filter(function(key) {
  return key != "letter";
})

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.groups = groupNames.map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      letter: d.letter,
      value: +d[name]
    };
  })
});



x0.domain(data.map(function(d) {  
  return d.letter;
}));
x1.domain(groupNames).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);

y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) {
  return d3.max(d.groups, function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });
})]);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Letter Fun");

var letter = svg.selectAll(".letter")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "g")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.letter) + ",0)";
  });

letter.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.groups;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {    
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  })
  .append("title")
  .text(function(d,i){
     var name = d.name.replace(/^./,d.name[0].toUpperCase());
     return "Letter : "+d.letter+" \n"+name+" : "+d.value;
   });

letter.selectAll("text")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.groups;
  })
  .enter().append("text")
  .attr("class", "barstext")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  })

var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(groupNames.slice().reverse())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
```

```css
body {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.bar {
  fill: steelblue;
}
.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<body></body>
```